# String encoding issue with Pythonika

Tags: interoperability, character-encoding, python

I use Mathematica and Pythonika to run Python code inside it. And I'm not quite sure what causes my issue: all `unicode` Python objects look like this: `А\.00л\.00е\.00к\.00с` (instead of `Александр`), i.e. there is an extra symbol after each letter, and thus the string is truncated (its length remains same). At the Pythonika page the author mentioned that unicode is supported, although not well-tested. Anyone experienced this? What are the possible workarounds?

Comment: It sounds like this is a Pythonika problem/bug in the C layer connecting Mathematica and Python.  Have you contacted the author of Pythonika?  I'd say the question is on the border of being off-topic ...  Unfortunately Pythonika is a bit sloppily implemented.  It is a useful package, but it's a quick and dirty implementation.  It would take considerably more work to implement a proper link.

Comment: Anyway, can you please give a *full* but minimal example that reproduces the problem?  Post the precise code that you used, but reduce it to the essentials (a few lines).  I'll take a look then.

Comment: @Szabolcs: oh, that was really a probably bug in Pythonika, didn't think about it being possible. I've fixed it (both for `unicode` and non-ascii `str`s), probably in a hacky way as I'm not quite good at C. Fix is available at http://hg.aplavin.ru/pythonika/

Comment: Excellent, thanks! (and +1 for the answer)

Comment: I wrote to the author once in the past but got no reply.  If it will be the same this time, we should collect these fixes somewhere.  I was also just playing with it and was planning to put it [here](https://github.com/szhorvat/Pythonika) (haven't pushed the changes yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by a bug in Pythonika. Fix is now available at http://hg.aplavin.ru/pythonika/, will send it to the author.